# Convert all *.mat files in a directory to *.txt files?

Tags: macos, matlab, text, directory

I want to convert all *.mat files in a directory to corresponding *.txt files
example, input : 100.mat
         output: 100.txt

I use the following code,

```
files = dir(‘*.mat’);
for file = files'
    mat = load(file.name);
    % Do some stuff
    %Conten = who;
    save('file.txt', Conten{:}, '-ascii')
end
```

but it returns all the lines into one big text file or just the content of the last file. I want to get all files converted to *.txt with the corresponding filenames.

Comment: Do your `.mat` files contain variables of `cellarray` and / or `struct` type?

Answer (score 1):

Some basic mistakes.....
Watch out save function, as you specified as:

save('file.txt', Conten{:}, '-ascii')

it indicates save everything into file.txt. Of cause you get that result.
In order to save into different file, you needs to generate file name every time.

```
something like these:
files = dir('*.mat');
for file = files'
    mat = load(file.name);
    % Do some stuff;
    %Conten = who;
    save(strcat(file.name, '.txt'), Conten{:}, '-ascii');
end
```

Comment: If the ".mat" file contains `cellarray` or `struct` variables you can not simply save them into an ASCII file with `save` because it does not support that data type.

Comment: While thats true, what i reckon from the question is he already successfully saved the text (Perhaps?), so i gave this answer.
More important, if there is anything like cellarray or struct, it should be eliminated in % Do some stuff; %Conten = who; and convert into appropriate string.

Answer (score 1):

```
files = dir('*.mat');
for file = 1:files
    mat = load(files(file).name);
    % Do some stuff
    %Conten = who;
    F_current=files(file).name
    F_name = strcat(a1(1:end-3),'txt')
    save(F_name, Conten{:}, '-ascii')
end
```